# How to define an 2byte integer in postgres sql using Flask-SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am using postgresql database, want to define a data type of integer value of 2 byte(0-65535). if it is more than 2 byte(65535) value, it shouldn't insert the data into db and raise an error .
Is there any data type to work with this scenario? or any check() functionality available for this ?

```
class Users(db.Model):
      id   = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three options for this. A `TypeDecorator` from SQLAlchemy, a DB-level "check-constraint" or a custom domain.

### Check Constraint

Simply apply the following on your column:

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD CONSTRAINT valid_2byte_int CHECK (id >= 0 AND id < 65535)
```

This has the advantage that it will work with whoever is connected to the DB. Whether it passes through application code or not. This (and the domain discussed below) are the safest options.

In SQLAlchemy you can then simply use the `sqlalchemy.Integer` type.

### Domain

You can define your own column-types with restrictions as so called "domains" inside the database. This is very similar and (in my opinion) better than a simple check-domain as you will be able to reuse it on other tables/columns and keeps things more tidy in general. To do this, simply run the following DB query:

```
CREATE DOMAIN uint2 AS integer
   CHECK(VALUE >= 0 AND VALUE < 65536);
```

You then *can* simply use the `sqlalchemy.Integer` type on you column and the DB will ensure it is valid, raising an appropriate error.

You can however also [override the type compilation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/custom_types.html#overriding-type-compilation) for more expressive code. I will leave this as an exercise to the reader ;)

### TypeDecorator

You can use a type-decorator for this as follows:

```
from sqlalchemy.engine.interfaces import Dialect
from sqlalchemy.types import Integer, TypeDecorator


class TwoByteInt(TypeDecorator):

    impl = Integer

    def process_bind_param(self, value: int, dialect: Dialect) -> int:
        if not (0 <= value < 65535):
            raise ValueError("Value must be between 0 and 65535")
        return value

    def process_result_value(self, value: int, dialect: Dialect) -> int:
        return value
```

And then use that type in your model definition:

```
class Users(db.Model):
      id   = db.Column(TwoByteInt, primary_key=True)
```

The `process_bind_param` function is called whenever a Python value needs to be converted to a DB value, and `process_result_value` does the inverse. Another way to think about it is: If the value travels from your application into the database, then it will first be processed by `process_bind_param`, and when it travels from the database to to your application, it will first be processed by `process_result_value`.

You can use these functions to do all kinds of checks & conversions in both directions. Here we're only interested in a simple value-check when the value is persisted to the DB, so we can leave the `process_result_value` dead-simple and pass the value transparently back to the caller. You could still do checks here if you really wanted to though.

Note that these functions are called *before* the SQL query is sent to the DB. So the database will never see these values. This may likely be what you want, but it's good to be aware that this will not be seen in any DB logs, and will also not trigger any DB-level constraint checks.

It might still be good to have a constraint-check on the DB though as discussed above if your SQLAlchemy-based application is not the only client on that DB.

See [Custom Types](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/custom_types.html) for more information.

Comment: In TypeDecorator section what is the use of ```impl = Integer```

Comment: It tells SA that it should use that type when compiling SQL statements.

Comment: @VivekKumar did this work for you? If yes, you might want to accept the answer

Comment: please have a look on my posted answer .

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to share how did i fixed in my db model.

```
from sqlalchemy import CheckConstraint
class Users(db.Model):
      id   = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
      __table_args__ = (
        CheckConstraint(id <= 65535, name='check_for_id'),
        {})
```

Comment: A small side-note: This will work only for when you are using SA to create the tables. If the table already exists and has data in it, you will need to either run the `alter table` statement I posted above, or use a migration toolkit like [`alembic`](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/) which will allow you to use the SA syntax to do the same.

Comment: And another minor thing: PostgreSQL integers are signed. So the check-constraint you defined will allow you to store negative values if you don't add a ` ... >= 0` condition.

Comment: @exhuma Agree. Thanks a lot.